# how to add google oauth login service in .NET MAUI

Tags: c#, .net, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, maui

I want to add Google Oauth 2.0 flow for the authorization purpose in .NET MAUI framework. How can i do that?

I just started working on .NET Maui framework , so it'll be helpful if I'll get step by step flow for the oauth service.

Comment: I've been following this topic (on my own) for a few. What I can tell so far, is that is not possible, for a few reasons. 1. Google has disabled the option from redirections from android app that would be required. 2. The same platform is not helping. 3. The library from xamarin is constantly bugging the current maui versions. Among other issues.
So, what I've opted in is to use regular user-password authentication. And eventually when it comes up a solution implement it later.